# Phonegap build: Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing facebook login using [Apache Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). The app is built in Phonegap build - android platform. It seems to be a very simple process to build, however I am stuck since yesterday in this error. My Steps:

Step 1. Add plugin in config.xml - My file is:

```
< ?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>42ch</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="My APP ID" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="MY APP NAME" />
    </gap:plugin>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
</widget>
```

Plugin Tab in phonegap build shows:
Plugin | Source | Version | Latest | Installed | Platforms
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect | pgb | 0.9.0 | 0.9.0 | 0.9.0 | android,ios

The line of code where the error comes (when I click a button login() is called):

```
var login = function() {
         if (!window.cordova) {
             facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit('MY APP ID'); // THE CODE WHERE ERROR OCCURS
             alert('a');
         }
         alert('b');
         facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], function(response) {
             alert('c');
             if (response.authResponse) {
                 facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', null,
                     function(response) {
                         alert('Good to see you, ' +
                             response.email + response.name + '.');
                     });

             }
         });
     }
```

Any help will be hugely appreciated. My code is at https://github.com/sandeepy02/42c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1517108,
it apparent this is your first app. Please read the [blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/) from now on. You have made two (2) mistakes related to recent blog posts.

1. We are now using NPM as a source for plugings. Please read [the blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/04/public-plugin-deprecation-on-build/).
2. You are using the wrong plugin. That version is non-grata (unwelcome for development). Use [this version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando).

Use this entry in place of what you have.

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" spec="0.11.0" />`

You should also [read the documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins) on *how to write a plugin entry*. This has changed. Read the [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two) for details. – Best of Luck.